# Magento Security Scan : some of results are UNKNOWN

Tags: security, ce-1.9.2.4, tools, security-scan-tool

I am trying magento's New Magento Security Scan and find out some of Unidentified Results.

Status of results are UNKNOWN.

**How can i completely scan my website**.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unknown means we cannot determine the information, eg for PHP version the server might not be exposing this in the headers (which is actually good) or your admin panel might be in non-standard location (which is good too). It's recommended you manually verify those unknown results to double check eg that you use SSL for admin panel or using up to date PHP version as we cannot check this automatically.

Comment: Hi Piotr, some time ago I changed whatever I could to make my website safe....r, then recently what I found is that my Website is now vulnerable and Mage-report is saying that there is a problem with "Brute force attacks? unprotected", however I already added everything what can help to protect my website into .htaccess, admin url is changed, rss is disabled and blocked via .htaccess. Seems like I still missing something but can't find what. Would you please advice what else I should check to make sure I'm safe?

Comment: If you provide me with the URL we can check what is happening (email me at peter @ magento.com ). If it is Magento 1, it might be /downloader as well.

Comment: Downloader removed, every other url removed or disabled or blocked/redirected, suspicious code removed .... still getting the same message. No idea why.